# Issue with AJAX "load more" button: disappears once clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

*EDIT:* thanks everyone for your help. It still doesn't work though. 
This script works **fine** if i change the **table to an ordered list**. (tr = ol and td = li)  That's why i really **think the issue comes from the append part of the code**. Any ideas?

Everything seems to work fine except for the "load more" button that disappears after it's been clicked. The new posts load but the users cannot click on the button again to load more posts. I've looked on SO but couldn't find a fix for my issue.

If I remove this line:

```
$("#more"+ID).remove();
```

then the button does show up but the gif image keeps on loading forever and the button is not clickable...

Here's the index.php code:

```
<table id="update_list" >
<tbody>
<?php
$result=query("SELECT * FROM postlist ORDER BY postid DESC LIMIT 9");
foreach ($result as $row)
{
$postid=$row['postid'];
$post=$row['post'];
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $postid ?>">
<td> 
<?php echo $post; ?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="more<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="morebox">
<a href="#" class="more" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>">more</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.more').live("click",function() 
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
if(ID)
{
$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="/loading.gif" />');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "loadmore.php",
data: "lastpost="+ ID, 
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#update_list >tbody").append(html);
$("#more"+ID).remove();
}
});
}
else
{
$(".morebox").html('The End');
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Here is the loadmore php page:

```
<?php
include("includes/config.php");
if(isset($_POST['lastpost']))
{
$lastpost=$_POST['lastpost'];

$result=query("SELECT * from postlist WHERE postid < '$lastpost' ORDER BY postid DESC 
LIMIT 5"); 


foreach ($result as $row){
$postid=$row['postid'];
$post=$row['post'];
?>
<tr id="<?php echo update$postid ?>">
<td>
<?php echo $post; ?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<div id="more<?php echo $postid; ?>" class="morebox">
<a href="#" class="more" id="<?php echo $postid; ?>">more</a>
</div>   
<?php  }?>
```

Any tips on what i'm doing wrong here ?
Thanks !

Comment: `echo update$postid` syntax error?

Comment: and `postid<'$lastpost'` - doesn't seem to "breathe".

Comment: Is  'load more' button is cell of table in which are you appending data.  I guess you are doing wrong there.

Comment: please dont use mysql_* function those are deprecated see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189 and your code is vulnerable to sql injection you need to escape all request properly

Comment: in addition the removing the '#more'+ID on success add the button back.

Comment: thank you all for your help. This script works fine if i change the table to an ordered list. (tr = ol and td = li) and bam ! it works like a charm. That's why i really think the issue comes from the append part of the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    
    $(function() {
    $('.more').live("click",function() 
    {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    if(ID)
    {
    $("#more"+ID).find("a").hide().insertAfter('<img src="/loading.gif" />'); //hide a link and insert image after it
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loadmore.php",
    data: "lastpost="+ ID, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#update_list >tbody").append(html);
    $("#more"+ID).find("img").remove(); // remove img
    $("#more"+ID).find("a").show();  //and show link
    }
    });
    }
    else
    {
    $(".morebox").html('The End');
    }
    return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesnt work. The new posts don't get loaded and the button load more doesn't appear...

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the `load more` button after button clicked

```
$("#update_list >tbody").append(html);
//$("#more"+ID).remove(); remove this line
```

Comment: he's replacing it with a loading gif before this. so if he does this instead of the more button he will get the image

Comment: @Orangepill True but he is removing the div as soon as the content is loading.

Comment: I'm just saying he needs to put the more link back so the user can click on it a second time. And it would be nice to remove or hide the loader gif.

Comment: @Orangepill Thanks for you input. When i remove this line, the button does appear once the results are loaded but, the gif image inside the button keeps on "loading" forever. And the button is not clickable either.  And if i remove the line containing the gif image, then the button is just empty. Any clue how to fix that ?

Comment: I would suggest placing both the image (with a display:none style) and the button in the #more+ID div and just use show and hide as needed.